Set Alt text for product images with the short description product with SQL for better SEO
I would like to update the alt description of an image assigned to a woocommerce product, and set it to the value of product short description.
I can select values like that
SELECT p.post_title, pm.meta_value AS alt_text 
FROM mod236_posts 
LEFT JOIN mod236_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
AND pm.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt' 
WHERE p.post_type = 'attachment' 
AND p.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%';

But I can't figure out the right MySQL query, this one affect  0 rows
UPDATE mod236_posts AS img
INNER JOIN mod236_postmeta AS sku_meta ON img.post_parent = sku_meta.post_id
SET img.post_excerpt = sku_meta.meta_value
WHERE img.post_type = 'attachment'
AND img.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%'
AND sku_meta.meta_key = '_wp_attachment_image_alt';

Where am I wrong ?

Is it possible that the post_excerpt column already contains the meta_value values? Also, the where clauses of the two queries are not the same.

yes it is possible, but it is mainly empty. Oh, my bad, it is fixed

Perhaps the product description is also empty for those images. It is difficult to tell you what goes wrong without sample data to test queries on.

Oh Sorry, Short description is never empty, but phpmyadmin tells me 0 rows affected.

You are setting the excerpt to the value of the alt description, but you state that you want to set the alt description. Confusing.

yes, it is correct. what is confusing ? alt description is empty, and I want to fill it with the value of excerpt which is always filled

This clearly sets the excerpt to the value of meta: SET img.post_excerpt = sku_meta.meta_value
